# Azure IoT Edge local storage backup and restore

Tags: backup, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

An IoT Edge device runs docker containers ("modules").  Those docker containers can have volumes or [bind mounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-access-host-storage-from-module?view=iotedge-1.4) with some local storage.  What is the recommended way to back up / restore these volumes?

The usual approach for backing up volumes requires running things on the host, but AFAIK IoT prefers running everything in modules and not on the host (at least when using deployment manifests).  It's also recommended to stop containers while doing backups, but IoT will get grumpy and automatically restart them if they're stopped (with a restart policy), unless I'm missing something.

Does the `$edgeAgent` support messages to explicitly stop/start modules?  I could only find one to [restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-edgeagent-direct-method?view=iotedge-1.4#restart-module), which is not what's needed here.

I want something that runs on schedule or manual command from the edge device itself, not commanded from the cloud.  In particular, re-deploying to change module run status is not something I want to do.

And I would prefer to deploy/update the backup solution itself via edge deployment, not manually.

---

Related: the device-to-cloud file upload API is only supported for devices and not modules, and yet as far as I can see there's no way for a module to authenticate as a device without putting a connection string or key somewhere that it shouldn't be.  Why is there no  `DeviceClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync`?  Or a way to obtain a device client from a module client?  Or is there something I'm missing there too?

Comment: Have you looked into [Azure Blob Storage on Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-store-data-blob?view=iotedge-1.4) module? The module is used to push data from edge to Azure Blob storage and is configurable through `uploadOn` deviceToCloudUploadProperties. Let me know if this addresses your use case

Comment: That's of possible interest for the second part but doesn't really address the main question.